# Montar una ISO para ver su contenido

Tags: windows, archivo

Estoy tratando de montar una ISO para ver el contenido completo de la misma. Estoy empleando Windows 10, y para ello hago uso de Daemon Tools para la montura de la ISO. La monta bien, pero a la hora de intentar abrir la imagen me salta el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que los datos **NO** están dañados, ya que desde un Linux copio la ISO en un disco duro externo mediante el comando `dd` de la forma `sudo dd if=imagen.iso of=/dev/sda` y me funciona correctamente al arrancarlo desde dicho disco duro exteno.

Mi pregunta puede enfocarse de si sabéis de otros programas, procedimientos, comandos, etc, que me permitan visualizar el contenido de la ISO una vez montada.
Tengo una máquina virtual con Ubuntu 18.04, por lo que me sirven comentarios tanto en W10 como para Linux.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: has probado a hacer lo mismo con otras ISOS? En caso de que con otras no te de problemas podemos descartar que sea problema del Daemon tools o algún fallo del S.O. Tiene pinta de que hay algún archivo dentro de esa ISO que está dando problemas o no es compatible 100% con Windows. Haz esa prueba y ya me dices. Saludos.

Comment: He probado a abrir otras ISOs y lo hace sin problema. Estoy pensando en la encriptación que se emplea al crear estas imágenes... ¿Es posible que tenga que abrir la ISO con el mismo programa con el que se creó? Por lo que tengo entendido, si por ejemplo haces un comprimido con WinRaR y luego quieres descomprimirla con 7-zip por ejemplo, hay veces que salta un error porque falla el método de encriptación. Seguiré probando cosas. De todos modos, gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Es posible que sea por lo que comentas. Yo probaría a crear esa ISO desde Windows con Daemon tools y ver que pasa.

Comment: Lo que podrías intentar hacer es en vez de montar la iso abrir la iso con winrar y ver si te deja descomprimir los archivos, sino o está dañado la imagen o tiene algun tipo de compresión que windows no la detecta por alguna razon